# jbd2 problems while writing to encrypted USB thumb drive

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, usb, luks

I'm seeing an error while writing to a LUKS-encrypted USB thumb drive that is known-good.
Could this be due to a bug in the jbd2 code?
I'm also using a Wifi driver that is ''tainted'' i.e. the Broadcom WL driver.

```
[209759.115096] INFO: task cp:900158 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[209759.115098]       Tainted: P        W  OE      6.1.0-15-amd64 #1 Debian 6.1.66-1
[209759.115099] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[209759.115100] task:cp              state:D stack:0     pid:900158 ppid:900157 flags:0x00004002
[209759.115103] Call Trace:
[209759.115104]  <TASK>
[209759.115105]  __schedule+0x34d/0x9e0
[209759.115107]  schedule+0x5a/0xd0
[209759.115109]  wait_transaction_locked+0x8a/0xd0 [jbd2]
[209759.115119]  ? cpuusage_read+0x10/0x10
[209759.115121]  add_transaction_credits+0x1a0/0x300 [jbd2]
[209759.115131]  ? ext4_es_insert_delayed_block+0x19b/0x2d0 [ext4]
[209759.115157]  start_this_handle+0x104/0x590 [jbd2]
[209759.115166]  ? jbd2__journal_start+0x90/0x1e0 [jbd2]
[209759.115175]  ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x148/0x300
[209759.115178]  jbd2__journal_start+0xf8/0x1e0 [jbd2]
[209759.115188]  __ext4_journal_start_sb+0x105/0x120 [ext4]
[209759.115212]  ext4_dirty_inode+0x34/0x80 [ext4]
[209759.115238]  __mark_inode_dirty+0x56/0x380
[209759.115241]  generic_write_end+0xf5/0x1a0
[209759.115243]  generic_perform_write+0x11a/0x210
[209759.115246]  ext4_buffered_write_iter+0x84/0x140 [ext4]
[209759.115271]  vfs_write+0x235/0x3e0
[209759.115274]  ksys_write+0x6b/0xf0
[209759.115277]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0xc0
[209759.115280]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x40
[209759.115283]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0xc0
[209759.115286]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0xc0
[209759.115288]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0xc0
[209759.115291]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0xc0
[209759.115294]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0xc0
[209759.115297]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0xc0
[209759.115300]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x64/0xce
[209759.115303] RIP: 0033:0x7f9c59924140
[209759.115304] RSP: 002b:00007ffc280dd608 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
[209759.115306] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000020000 RCX: 00007f9c59924140
[209759.115308] RDX: 0000000000020000 RSI: 00007f9c5976d000 RDI: 0000000000000005
[209759.115309] RBP: 0000000000020000 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
[209759.115310] R10: 0000000000000022 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 00007f9c5976d000
[209759.115311] R13: 0000000000000005 R14: 0000000000020000 R15: 00007f9c5976d000
[209759.115314]  </TASK>
```